# Can the iterator of a set be used to find difference between two consecutive elements of the set, in c++?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set

/* [What I have done in the following code is running forever, what should I edit to get the desired difference between consecutive set elements?] */

## include

using namespace std;

int main() {

```
int temp;
set <int> sett ;
set <int>:: iterator itr;
int n=5 ;
itr= sett.begin();


for (int i=0;i<n ; i++){

    cin>> temp ;
    sett.insert(temp);


}

for( itr = sett.begin();itr!=sett.end();itr++){
    if(itr!=sett.end()){
        cout << (*itr++)-(*itr) << " difference"<< endl ;
    }

}


return 0;
```

}

Comment: Use [std::distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can the iterator of a set be used to find difference between two consecutive elements of the set, in c++?

Yes.

> ```
> for( itr = sett.begin();itr!=sett.end();itr++){
> //                                      ^^^^^
>     if(itr!=sett.end()){    
>         cout << (*itr++)-(*itr) << " difference"<< endl ;
> //                ^^^^^
> ```

The problem here is that you increment the iterator twice, so you skip elements. furthermore, in case of iterator to last element, you end up indirecting through the iterator past the last element (i.e. the end iterator).

There is actually a standard algorithm for this. Its name is generally considered confusing, but in this use case, it is actually quite appropriate. Meet `std::adjacent_difference`:

```
std::adjacent_difference(std::begin(sett), std::end(sett),
    std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " difference\n"));
```

Comment: Thanks for a very descriptive answer. I have got my answer and many new things which I yet need to understand and learn. For example: while checking for adjacent_difference many unknown things have come in front of me. Eg. The 3rd argument, of your instance is something I know nothing of.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to SO.

in order to get the last element of your set you've to create a temporary variable, pointing to that element.
An example would look like this:

```
std::set<int> elements{};
if(!elements.empty()) {
    auto it = elements.begin();
    const int* last_element{&*(it++)}; /* if elements would be empty this would be undefined behaviour */
    while(it != elements.end()) {
        const auto now = *it++;
        const auto diff = last_element - now;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir thanks for your idea I will definitely make use of your insights and try to learn from it ; and the "welcome" part really was special for a complete newbie like me. It created an emotional push which is not something I was expecting here( but of course loved it, much appreciated)